# is there a way to log on and save the account/password (stay logged on)?

Tags: discussion, login

Is there a way to save the username/password (login) on the browser app? It is a bit annoying to always click on the "Exchange" button, then re-type my account credentials.

Probably there is a feature as in Facebook to enter the login page while my account credentials are already displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have cookies enabled and a modern browser you should already have this feature.

The sites use **something** <strike>"new" called local storage (correct me if I'm wrong)</strike> that should keep you logged in.

You shouldn't have to log in every time.

Comment: Yes, cookies. Not local storage.

Comment: @Trufa: i meant if i close the browser, and re-open it, like a "facebook" save-me-on-this-machine feature?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thanks, is local storage for cross site login or am I just making things up as I go?

Comment: @NirMH: That should already be the case, if you have cookies enabled!

Comment: @Trufa: I'm not aware that SE uses local storage for anything, although that doesn't mean they do not make use of it in some way.

Comment: @Robert, not really related to this topic, but SE does use local storage for chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @PopularDemand: I knew I wasn't **so** crazy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already logged in an SE site, and you visit another SE site where you already have an account, but you didn't visit it (for example) in the last month, you should be automatically logged in, and see something similar to what shown in the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXrai.png).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That applies to every site, not only cross site.